# SHA256 For Ruby Not Working On Mac

Tags: ruby, sha256

On my mac 10.5 when I use the command OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha256') I get Unsupported digest algorithm (sha256). Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The OS X supplied Ruby 1.8.6p287 does not seem to have this compiled in, however the one bundled with MacPorts, 1.8.7p160 does have it.

It's generally better to use the MacPorts version since it is more up-to-date.